# JUnit testing of programmatic UI layout

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, android-layout, junit

I have a series of Java classes which have programmatic UI layouts; the structure of the layouts varies throughout the running of the classes and is dependent on user responses so I cannot create them as fixed layouts in an xml file.  I am now at the stage that I need to test the classes and am wrestling with the Android ans Eclipse testing using JUnit.  I cannot seem to workout how to test these programmatic UI's as their id's are assigned when they are created.  I know what the id's are  (I assign the id using `setId(100 +i)` where i is the loop variable) but cannot access these id's in the test project.  I have tried `findViewById(SandS.Med.NurseCalc.101)` but it does not seem to work.  I am trying this in  my `setUp()` module.
Can anyone either help with this item or point me in the direction of a site that looks at testing in a more practical way rather than the rather theoretical and complex way in the android.developer site.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to test it using the Android JUnit tool if at all possible.  I am finding getting to grips with one concept more than enough at the moment without getting into mocking too.  I would appreciate anyone's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find mocking extremely usefull for testing programatic android stuff.  I recommend jMockit
for this purpose ( IMHO, best mocking framework around )

In this unit test I test specific Vew retrieval:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/test/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/ViewInjectionTest.java

Comment: I was really hoping not to have to get into something else.  But hey, ho; if you think it is the best way, I will give it a go.  I have looked at your code and it seems very helpful, thanks.  
However, I was really hoping that there would be a way using JUnit or the Android testing that comes with the SDK.

Comment: I found provided SDK tools not adequate.  Mocking is extremely useful for TDD ( and also in other contexts )  - see this as scripted debugging session. You just specify how your class shall interact with outher systems ( like overriden activity methods etc ) without need to create objects -  and you can not create android objects, or call methods because android librries are completely neutered ( all methods are stubbed out to throw ruintime exception )  - you can only compile against them